# Powershell Invoke-Expressions pauses

Tags: powershell

I wrote a Powershell script that uses Steam's command line tool to login and check for updates for a community server I am running. See below:

```
$steamcmdFolder = 'C:\download\steam'
$steamcmdExec = $steamcmdFolder+"\steamcmd.exe"
$forceinstall = 'force_install_dir'+$steamcmdFolder
$appupdate = 'app_update 258550'
$cmdOutput = "$steamcmdExec +login anonymous"

do  {

Write-Host Checking for an update....

Invoke-Expression $cmdOutput
Invoke-expression $forceinstall
Invoke-expression $appupdate

} 

while ($Update = 1)
```

---

The Invoke-Expression lines are individual command-line statements I want executed in the order I have them. For some reason, the first Invoke-Expression works fine but the others do not -- everything just stops. I can type in the value of $forceinstall on the PowerShell command-line and it works as expected. But why can't I do this using PowerShell? Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert the other two lines down to what they are, it seems like they are not real commands.

```
#Invoke-expression $forceinstall
Invoke-Expression "force_install_dirC:\download\steam"
#Invoke-expression $appupdate
Invoke-Expression "app_update 258550"
```

Looking into the [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) documents, it appears that you might want to change it to be a single line command.

```
Invoke-Expression "steamcmd +login anonymous +force_install_dir C:\download\steam +app_update 258550 +quit"
```

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` is unnecessary.